# activitymimeattachments and filesize issue

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

I seem to be unable to work with the filesize property of the activitymimeattachments object correctly (not even in v9.1 of Microsoft Dynamics Web API).

It started with the fact Dynamics didn't sort attachments according to this property:

```
/api/data/v9.1/activitymimeattachments?$select=activitymimeattachmentid,filename,filesize,subject&$filter=(some condition)&$orderby=filesize%20desc
```

The orderby parameter is completely ignored. More over when adding filesize to the filtering part of the api, the api doesn't return any attachment (in builds main JSON though):

```
/api/data/v9.1/activitymimeattachments?$select=activitymimeattachmentid,filename,filesize,subject&$filter=filesize gt 100&$orderby=filesize desc
```

Is this some sort of a bug? Other objects work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In v9.1 this appears to be working for me:

`https://myDevOrg.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/activitymimeattachments?$select=filesize&$top=10&$filter=filesize%20gt%201000&$orderby=filesize%20desc`

[image: results]